# How to resolve a gem dependency conflict after installing email_spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, email-spec

I just installed email-spec for use with rspec according to the instructions in the [readme](https://github.com/bmabey/email-spec#rspec). Now, when I try to run a test (even without using email-spec's methods in my specs) I get this error:

```
$ rspec spec
Neither Pony nor ActionMailer appear to be loaded so email-spec is requiring ActionMailer.
WARN: Unresolved specs during Gem::Specification.reset:
      launchy (~> 2.1)
      builder (~> 3.1)
WARN: Clearing out unresolved specs.
Please report a bug if this causes problems.
/Users/jpalmieri/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.7.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:34:in `block in setup': You have already activated minitest 5.4.0, but your Gemfile requires minitest 4.7.5. Prepending `bundle exec` to your command may solve this. (Gem::LoadError)
    from /Users/jpalmieri/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.7.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:19:in `setup'
    from /Users/jpalmieri/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.7.4/lib/bundler.rb:121:in `setup'
    from /Users/jpalmieri/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.7.4/lib/bundler/setup.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/jpalmieri/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:128:in `require'
    from /Users/jpalmieri/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:128:in `rescue in require'
    from /Users/jpalmieri/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:39:in `require'
    from /Users/jpalmieri/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
    from /Users/jpalmieri/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/jpalmieri/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
    from /Users/jpalmieri/workspace/blocitoff/config/boot.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/jpalmieri/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:121:in `require'
    from /Users/jpalmieri/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:121:in `require'
    from /Users/jpalmieri/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
    from /Users/jpalmieri/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/jpalmieri/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
    from /Users/jpalmieri/workspace/blocitoff/config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/jpalmieri/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:121:in `require'
    from /Users/jpalmieri/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:121:in `require'
    from /Users/jpalmieri/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
    from /Users/jpalmieri/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/jpalmieri/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
    from /Users/jpalmieri/workspace/blocitoff/config/environment.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/jpalmieri/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:121:in `require'
    from /Users/jpalmieri/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:121:in `require'
    from /Users/jpalmieri/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
    from /Users/jpalmieri/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/jpalmieri/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
    from /Users/jpalmieri/workspace/blocitoff/spec/rails_helper.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/jpalmieri/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:121:in `require'
    from /Users/jpalmieri/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:121:in `require'
    from /Users/jpalmieri/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
    from /Users/jpalmieri/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/jpalmieri/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
    from /Users/jpalmieri/workspace/blocitoff/spec/features/mark_todo_complete_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/jpalmieri/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
    from /Users/jpalmieri/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `block in load'
    from /Users/jpalmieri/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/jpalmieri/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
    from /Users/jpalmieri/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1105:in `block in load_spec_files'
    from /Users/jpalmieri/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1105:in `each'
    from /Users/jpalmieri/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1105:in `load_spec_files'
    from /Users/jpalmieri/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:96:in `setup'
    from /Users/jpalmieri/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:84:in `run'
    from /Users/jpalmieri/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:69:in `run'
    from /Users/jpalmieri/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:37:in `invoke'
    from /Users/jpalmieri/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/jpalmieri/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/bin/rspec:23:in `load'
    from /Users/jpalmieri/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/bin/rspec:23:in `<main>'
```

Prepending `bundle exec` will make the tests run fine (I still get the `Neither Pony nor ActionMailer appear to be loaded so email-spec is requiring ActionMailer` notice, but I guess that's a topic for a different post).

Here's my Gemfile. I don't explicitly call minitest, so I'm assuming that it's a dependency of email_spec and something else.

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.0.10'

gem 'devise'
gem 'figaro', '1.0'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.1'
gem 'timecop'
gem 'pundit'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'capybara'
end

# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end

group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :test do
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '~> 4.0'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'email_spec'
end

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.2'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'

# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'

group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]
```

I tried resolving the conflict by adding `gem 'minitest', '~> 4.7.5'` to my `:test` group, but still get the same error.

```
group :test do
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '~> 4.0'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'email_spec'
  gem 'minitest', '~> 4.7.5'
end
```

My questions are:

1) I've never had to prepend `bundle exec` before. Should I try to resolve the conflict instead of prepending `bundle exec`?

2) If "yes" to question 1, how would I go about doing this?

Comment: The question on the `Neither Pony nor ActionMailer appear to be loaded so email-spec is requiring ActionMailer` notice was answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29183573/rspec-email-spec-issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because the Gem specifies an older version of MiniTest in its dependencies, and you have a newer version installed on your system.

Using `bundle exec` is the correct way. Please see the below:

> When running an executable, ALWAYS use bundle exec [command]. Quoting from the bundler documentation: In some cases, running executables without bundle exec may work, if the executable happens to be installed in your system and does not pull in any gems that conflict with your bundle. However, this is unreliable and is the source of considerable pain.

http://yehudakatz.com/2011/05/30/gem-versioning-and-bundler-doing-it-right/