# Rspec email_spec issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rubygems, capybara, rspec3

I am going through this User Authentication tutorial..

http://larsgebhardt.de/user-authentication-with-ruby-on-rails-rspec-and-capybara/

..which uses the gem 'email_spec'. Granted the author is using an earlier version of rails and rspec, I am having issues getting the gem to work properly.

When adding..

**spec_helper.rb**

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
...
config.include(EmailSpec::Helpers)
config.include(EmailSpec::Matchers)
...
end
```

I receive the error..

```
Neither Pony nor ActionMailer appear to be loaded so email-spec is requiring ActionMailer.
WARN: Unresolved specs during Gem::Specification.reset:
      minitest (~> 5.1)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.2)
WARN: Clearing out unresolved specs.
Please report a bug if this causes problems.
```

I can still see the expected test failures so I continued, but once I got to the part where it had me add `config.include(UserHelper)` to the spec_helper, the gem or test suite broke.

This side of rails and rspec is a little over my head. Any help is highly appreciated.

I am currently running Rails 4.1.6 and Rspec 3.1.7.

Comment: What happens if you prepend `bundle exec` to the command you use to run your specs?

Comment: @Drenmi -  I unfortunately receive the exact same error without the WARN notices.

Comment: I'm having trouble reproducing the issue. Do you have a repository where you could share your application?

Comment: @Drenmi - Yes it is: https://github.com/shroy/mixblog Thank you for taking the time to help. I disabled the line `config.include(UserHelper)` in the **spec_helper.rb** so you see the first error.

Comment: I fixed the issues and outlined the answer below. I also opened a pull request to your GitHub repository with the code fixes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems to fix here.

Firstly, there is the notice from the `email_spec` gem. To get rid of this, simply require `action_mailer` before `email_spec` in your `rails_helper.rb`:

```
require "action_mailer"
require "email_spec"
```

Actually the `email_spec` gem will do this for you (hence the notice), but if you want to get rid of the pesky message, this is the solution.

Secondly, there is the issue of `config.include(UserHelper)`. This is actually unrelated to the first issue, and happens because the `support/user_helper.rb` file is not included when you try to reference the `UserHelper` module.

The reason this happens is because the article you're following was written before RSpec 3, and thus before the Rails configurations moved to the `rspec_helper.rb` file. (More information on the upgrade here: https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/upgrade)

To resolve the problem:

1. Uncomment this line from `rails_helper.rb`:

   `Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each { |f| require f }`

   This will load all your files from the `spec/support` directory tree.
2. Move all your configurations from `spec_helper.rb` to `rails_helper.rb`.

Comment: It's working out great now. Thank you for diving into this one!