# Rspec & Capybara: uninitialized constant SessionController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, rspec, capybara

I am following along this tutorial's authentication process - currently on the section 'User Authentication':

http://larsgebhardt.de/user-authentication-with-ruby-on-rails-rspec-and-capybara/

I received the follower test failure:

```
  1) User Management User log in
     Failure/Error: login(@writer)
     ActionController::RoutingError:
       uninitialized constant SessionController
     # ./spec/support/user_helper.rb:6:in `login'
     # ./spec/features/users_spec.rb:27:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Here is the specific test and helper file mention in the failure message, along with other files..

**spec/features/users_spec.rb**

```
require 'spec_helper'

    background do
      @writer = create(:user, :writer)
    end

   ....

    scenario 'User log in' do
      activate(@writer)
      login(@writer)
      expect(page).to have_content "Successfully logged in."
    end
```

**spec/support/user_helper.rb**

```
module UserHelper


  def login(a)
    visit root_path
    click_link 'Log In'
    fill_in 'session[email]', with: a.email
    fill_in 'session[password]', with: a.password
    click_button 'Log In'
  end

  def logout(a)
    visit root_path
    click_link 'Log Out'
  end

  def activate(a)
    visit activate_path(:code => a.activation_code)
  end

end
```

**routes.rb**

```
resources :session
```

**sessions_controller.rb**

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController


  def new
  end

  def create
    user = User.find_by_email(params[:session][:email]).try(:authenticate, params[:session][:password])
    if user
        if user.is_active?
            session[:user_id] = user.id
            redirect_to (session[:target_url] || root_path)
                flash[:notice] = "Successfully logged in."
            else
                redirect_to new_session_path
                flash[:error] = "Account inactive. Please activate your account."
            end
        else
            redirect_to new_session_path
            flash[:error] = "Invalid email or password."
        end
  end

  def destroy
    session[:user_id] = nil
    redirect_to root_path
    flash[:notice] = "Successfully logged out."
  end

end
```

**new.html.erb**

```
<h1>Log In</h1>

<%= form_for :session, url: sessions_path do |f| %>

    <div>
        <%= f.label :email %>
        <%= f.text_field :email %>
    </div>

    <div>
        <%= f.label :password %>
        <%= f.password_field :password %>
    </div>

    <div>
        <%= f.submit 'Log In' %>
    </div>

<% end %>
```

**rake routes**

```
    Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                 Controller#Action
    profiles_show GET    /profiles/show(.:format)                    profiles#show
     sessions_new GET    /sessions/new(.:format)                     sessions#new
        users_new GET    /users/new(.:format)                        users#new
             root GET    /                                           sessions#new
    post_comments GET    /posts/:post_id/comments(.:format)          comments#index
                  POST   /posts/:post_id/comments(.:format)          comments#create
 new_post_comment GET    /posts/:post_id/comments/new(.:format)      comments#new
edit_post_comment GET    /posts/:post_id/comments/:id/edit(.:format) comments#edit
     post_comment GET    /posts/:post_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#show
                  PATCH  /posts/:post_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#update
                  PUT    /posts/:post_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#update
                  DELETE /posts/:post_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#destroy
            posts GET    /posts(.:format)                            posts#index
                  POST   /posts(.:format)                            posts#create
         new_post GET    /posts/new(.:format)                        posts#new
        edit_post GET    /posts/:id/edit(.:format)                   posts#edit
             post GET    /posts/:id(.:format)                        posts#show
                  PATCH  /posts/:id(.:format)                        posts#update
                  PUT    /posts/:id(.:format)                        posts#update
                  DELETE /posts/:id(.:format)                        posts#destroy
         sessions GET    /sessions(.:format)                         sessions#index
                  POST   /sessions(.:format)                         sessions#create
      new_session GET    /sessions/new(.:format)                     sessions#new
     edit_session GET    /sessions/:id/edit(.:format)                sessions#edit
          session GET    /sessions/:id(.:format)                     sessions#show
                  PATCH  /sessions/:id(.:format)                     sessions#update
                  PUT    /sessions/:id(.:format)                     sessions#update
                  DELETE /sessions/:id(.:format)                     sessions#destroy
            users GET    /users(.:format)                            users#index
                  POST   /users(.:format)                            users#create
         new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)                        users#new
        edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)                   users#edit
             user GET    /users/:id(.:format)                        users#show
                  PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)                        users#update
                  PUT    /users/:id(.:format)                        users#update
                  DELETE /users/:id(.:format)                        users#destroy
    profile_index GET    /profile(.:format)                          profile#index
                  POST   /profile(.:format)                          profile#create
      new_profile GET    /profile/new(.:format)                      profile#new
     edit_profile GET    /profile/:id/edit(.:format)                 profile#edit
          profile GET    /profile/:id(.:format)                      profile#show
                  PATCH  /profile/:id(.:format)                      profile#update
                  PUT    /profile/:id(.:format)                      profile#update
                  DELETE /profile/:id(.:format)                      profile#destroy
         activate GET    /activate/:code(.:format)                   users#activate
```

**_header.html.erb**

```
<a href="#">About</a>
<a href="#">Services</a>
<a href="#"><%= link_to "Sign Up", new_user_path %></a>
<a href="#"><%= link_to "Log In", new_session_path %></a>
<a href="#"><%= link_to "Log Out", "/session", method: :delete %></a>
```

I previously had an issue with configuring the User Helper file which was solved but incase it becomes relevant, you can see the answer and state of the config file here:

[Rspec email_spec issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29183573/rspec-email-spec-issue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `resources :sessions`, you are missing the 's'.

Edit :

You are using the delete route incorrectly, you should say

```
<%= link_to "Log Out",session_path(pass the current signed in user here) , method: :delete %>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I'm still getting this error `Failure/Error: login(@writer)
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"sessions"} missing required keys: [:id]`.  What confuses me is that I didn't think I need a 'show' action which is why assumed the author kept the route 'session' as singular.

Comment: @Shroy have you defined a root ? You need `root "sessions#new`" in your routes.rb

Comment: Ya my defined root is `posts#index`. It's a blog and I'm trying to create an authentication system that has an 'admin', `writers`, and `visitors` that can only comment. The man root page displays all posts.

Comment: @Shroy please add the new full error to the question.

Comment: It appears the login works now! Now the logout route is having an issue. `2) User Management User log out
     Failure/Error: logout(@writer)
     ActionController::RoutingError:
       No route matches [DELETE] "/session"`

Comment: Definitely! Edited my post to include it.

Comment: @Shroy you would need to show your rake routes and your index page as well, it appears the problem is either you don't have the route, or you are using it incorrectly.

Comment: I tried adding `session_path(current_user)` which is the method in my **profiles_controller.rb** file. Following along the tutorial that would be his **offices_controller.rb**. But now I'm receiving the error `Failure/Error: activate(@writer) ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method 'current_user' for #<SessionsController:0x007fd2029c8d68>` By the comments in the tutorial only a couple modifications needed to be made for Rails 4. I'm confused why so much isn't working for me. :/

Comment: @Shroy it means that we fixed the previous errors. now you can ask a new question about the new error.